# Import ES modules for ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, node-modules, openlayers

I'm using the Open Layers convention of

```
var osm_default = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM()
});
```

but how do I handle

```
var dragBoxInteraction = new DragBox({
  condition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly,
```

Everything else is handled via

```
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON.js';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature.js';
import Style from 'ol/style/Style';
import Stroke from 'ol/style/Stroke.js';
import {defaults} from 'ol/interaction/defaults';
import {transform} from 'ol/proj.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
// the following doesn't work. A SWAG
import {shiftKeyOnly} from 'ol​/events​/condition';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was close. `import {shiftKeyOnly} from 'ol/events/condition.js';`

Comment: I think you want to rewrite the text coming with the code. Your post ended up in the "low quality answer" queue .... so maybe do something to improve it.